# Minimax Alogrithm for TicTacToe [python]

Tags: python, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax, minmax

I'm trying to implement the minimax algorithm in my tic tac toe game. I watched several videos, analysed multiple programs with minimax algorithm and I think I do know how it works now. My program is working but it seems like the algorithm has no clue what he is doing. It outputs pads on the board but it doesn't block me or tries to win. Like it's random. It would be nice if someone could have a look at my minimax algorithm and tell what's wrong! It would also be nice to tell me whats wrong with my explanation and don't just downvote.

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Board:
    def __init__(self, board=None):
        self.winning_combos = (
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6])

        if board is not None:
            self.board = board
        else:
            self.board = [None for i in range(9)]

    def check_combos(self):
        """ checks every combo if its used """
        for symbol in ['X', 'O']:
            for win_comb in self.winning_combos:
                sum = 0
                for field in win_comb:
                    if self.board[field] == symbol:
                        sum += 1

                if sum == 3:
                    return symbol

        return None

    def complete(self):
        """ check if the game is complete, caused by win or draw """
        cc = self.check_combos()
        if cc is not None:
            return cc

        if len(self.empty_pads()) <= 0:
            return "DRAW"

        return False

    def show(self):
        """ print board """
        print(str(self.board[0:3]) + "\n" +
              str(self.board[3:6]) + "\n" +
              str(self.board[6:9]))

    def empty_pads(self):
        """ returns list with indexes of every unused/empty field/pad """
        list = []
        for pad in range(len(self.board)):
            if self.board[pad] is None:
                list.append(pad)

        return list

    def set(self, position, player):
        """ sets the players symbol on the given position """
        self.board[position] = player

    def copy(self):
        return deepcopy(self)


def get_enemy_player(player):
    if player == 'X':
        return 'O'
    return 'X'


def get_player_value(player):
    """ X = max, O = min """
    if player == 'X':
        return 1
    else:
        return -1


def get_player_by_value(value):

    if value == -1:
        return "O"
    elif value == 1:
        return "X"
    else:
        return "NONE"


def max_v(node):
    if node.depth == 0 or node.board.complete():
        return get_player_value(node.board.complete())

    bestVal = -100
    for child in node.children:
        v = minimax(child)
        if v >= bestVal:
            bestVal = v
            node.bestmove = child.move

    return bestVal


def min_v(node):
    if node.depth == 0 or node.board.complete():
        return get_player_value(node.board.complete())

    bestVal = 100
    for child in node.children:
        v = minimax(child)
        if v <= bestVal:
            bestVal = v
            node.bestmove = child.move

    return bestVal


def minimax(node):
    if node.depth == 0 or node.board.complete():
        return get_player_value(node.board.complete())

    if get_player_value(node.player) == 1:
        return max_v(node)
    elif get_player_value(node.player) == -1:
        return min_v(node)


class Node:
    def __init__(self, depth, player, board, pad):
        self.depth = depth
        self.player = player
        self.board = board
        self.move = pad
        self.board.set(pad, self.player)
        self.bestmove = int

        self.children = []
        self.CreateChildren()

    def CreateChildren(self):
        if self.depth > 0 and not self.board.complete():
            for index in self.board.empty_pads():
                board = self.board.copy()
                self.children.append(Node(self.depth - 1, get_enemy_player(self.player), board, index))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    board = Board()
    board.show()

    while not board.complete():
        player = 'X'
        player_move = int(input('Move: ')) - 1
        if player_move not in board.empty_pads():
            continue
        board.set(player_move, player)
        board.show()

        if board.complete():
            break
        player = get_enemy_player(player)
        node = Node(9, player, board.copy(), player_move)
        minmax = minimax(node)
        print(node.bestmove+1)
        for child in node.children:
            print("move: " + str(child.move + 1) + " --> " + get_player_by_value(minmax) + " win")

        board.set(node.bestmove, player)
        board.show()

    print(board.complete())
```

PS: I do know why the "moves: " ouput is always the same, but that's not the point.

Comment: acctually the module is unused. I took it out. Also I tried to explain what my program is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple issues in your program.

As for your actual question: Your program acts as if the computer does not distinguish between a loss for it and a draw. Nowhere in your code can I find you assigning a value of 0 for a draw, while it appears you assign 1 for a win and -1 for a loss. Your code should prefer a draw to a loss but it sees no difference. That is why it looks "Like it's random". My analysis here may be off, but the following issues explain why it is difficult for me to tell.

Your style should be improved, to improve readability and ease of maintenance and to avoid bugs. Your code is much too difficult for me to understand, partly because...

- You have far too few comments for anyone other than you to understand what the code is trying to do. In a few months you will not be able to remember, so write it down in the code.
- You have too many blank lines, violating [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) and making harder to see much code on the screen.
- You do not take your output seriously enough, as shown when you say "ou[t]put is always the same, but that's not the point." It is hard for anyone, including you, to tell what is happening in your code without good output. Work on that, and add some temporary print or logging statements that tell you more about what is happening inside.
- Some of your routines return values of varying types. The `complete()` function sometimes returns the string `"DRAW"`, sometimes the Boolean `False`, and sometimes a value from `self.check_combos()`, whatever type that is. Your routines `max_v()` and `min_v()` sometimes return a string value from `get_player_value()` and sometimes an integer from variable `bestVal`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I'm gonna try to improve my coding style so that others can understand it also ;)